# Android - NavigationDrawer Адаптер

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. Сижу, пишу адаптер для объекта ListView с выводом "минипрофиля" и, как бы грамотно выразить, заголовком категории... В общем, хочу сделать что-то в [таком](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/183e168c-180c-4127-8739-dbf80348af82.1397385882.png) роде. Имеются 2 массива строк и иконок

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>Главная</item>
    <item>Игры для ПК</item>
    <item>Игры для PSP</item>
    <item>Игры для XBOX</item>
    <item>Android</item>
    <item>Фильмы HD</item>
    <item>Программы</item>
    <item>Обои для ПК</item>
    <item>Музыка</item>
    <item>iPhone/iPad</item>
    <item>Журналы</item>
</string-array>

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_pc</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_psp</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_xbox</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_android</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_video</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_software</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_wallpapers</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_music</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_apple</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_book</item>
</array>
```

В MainActivity()

```
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListProfile navDrawerListProfile;
private NavDrawerListCategory navDrawerListCategory;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
// начинается метод onCreate()
navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
navDrawerListProfile = new NavDrawerListProfile(preferences.getString("login", null), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
navDrawerListCategory = new NavDrawerListCategory("Основные разделы");
navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)));
}
navMenuIcons.recycle();
adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerListProfile, navDrawerListCategory, navDrawerItems);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В общем в конструктор адаптера я передаю объект для вывода "минипрофиля", "заголовка" (так буду называть) и набор пунктов меню (категорий). Вся беда начинается в адаптере:

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListCategory navDrawerListCategory;
private NavDrawerListProfile navDrawerListProfile;
LayoutInflater mInflater;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, NavDrawerListProfile navDrawerListProfile, NavDrawerListCategory navDrawerListCategory, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    this.navDrawerListCategory = navDrawerListCategory;
    this.navDrawerListProfile = navDrawerListProfile;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size() + 2;
}

boolean isSelectable(int position) {
    if(position == 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {   
    if(position == 0)
        return navDrawerListProfile;
    if(position == 1)
        return navDrawerListProfile;
    if(position > 1)
        return navDrawerItems.get(position - 2);

    return navDrawerItems.get(0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(position == 0)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_profile, null);
        if(position == 1)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_category, null);
        if(position > 1)
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    if(position == 0) {
        ImageView mainMenuAvatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuAvatar);
        TextView mainMenuUsername = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuUsername);
        TextView mainMenuMyProfile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuMyProfile);
        mainMenuAvatar.setImageResource(navDrawerListProfile.getAvatar());
        mainMenuUsername.setText(navDrawerListProfile.getLogin());
        if(mainMenuUsername.getText().equals("Гость"))
            mainMenuMyProfile.setText("Авторизуйтесь");
    }
    if(position == 1) {
        TextView mainMenuCategoryTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainMenuCategoryTitle);
        mainMenuCategoryTitle.setText(navDrawerListCategory.getTitle());
    }
    if(position > 1) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "position = " + (position - 2) + "; max = " + (navDrawerItems.size() - 1));
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawerIcon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawerTitle);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawerCounter);
        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getTitle());
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getCounterVisibility())
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        else
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Тут я пытаюсь возвращать объект "минипрофиля" если позиция == 0, если позиция == 1, то объект "заголовок", в остальных случаях - пункты меню (категории). Вся проблема в том, что на этих:

```
imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getTitle());
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position - 2).getCounterVisibility())
```

строчках вылетает NullPointerException. Если убрать везде - 2 и + 2, то работает все, конечно, как надо, но первые 2 категории не видны (видимо вытягиваю не те ресурсы, индекс не тот). В таком случае пунктов меню ровно на 2 меньше (как и новых добавленных: "минипрофиль" и "заголовок"). Что я не так делаю? Уже двое суток убил на этот адаптер.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду копать)
upd. Нашел. Сделал. Работает.
Спасибо огромное))

Comment: это я и сам понимаю, ставлю не сразу, ибо не всегда комментарий можно пометить как правильный ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слабо понял где не работает, но посмотрите на методы getViewTypeCount() и getItemViewType(int position). После того как переопределите их, адаптер в getView будет выбирать правильный View и проблема должна исчезнуть.